# Integration by substitution doesn't work ... Why?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I had this problem in my Math workbook:

$$\int_0^{52.95}\sqrt{100-84\exp(-0.016t)} \, dt $$

I took a substitution of    $u = 100-84\exp(-0.016t)$

such that $dt = 0.744\exp(0.016t) du$

After working through the problem, the answer came out as (approx.) $566$.

This was not the same as the answer in the book, which actually solved it numerically using the trapezium rule. So I fired Wolfram|Alpha to find out how to get an exact answer using substitution. Wolfram did have the same answer as the book, and the step-by-step solution used $3-4$ substitutions.

My question is, why didn't my substitution work?

P.S: The answer in the book is $342$.

Comment: "This was to the same...": Do you mean "This was not the same..."?

Comment: @TonyK, yes, fixed.

Comment: It seems like your dt isn't correct.  You should have something like $dt = f(u)du$.

Comment: @YoussefSami: Check your question before posting it. Changing the question frequently seems no good. :-)

Comment: In my comment I was not pointing out a typo.  What I meant was that you seem to have a mistaken approach for calculating $dt$.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I realize that, and I hope you clarify on the mistake because I just double checked.

Comment: @YoussefSami: `84*0.016=1.344`

Comment: @B.S. I see this, but 1/1.344 = 0.744 and I switched the sign in the exp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your $dt$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & u=100-84\cdot e^{-0.016t}\\
 & \Rightarrow & du=-84\cdot\left(-0.016\right)e^{-0.016t}dt\\
 & \Rightarrow & dt=\frac{1}{84\cdot0.016}\cdot e^{0.016t}\, du
\end{eqnarray*}
Also
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & u=100-84\cdot e^{-0.016t}\\
 & \Rightarrow & \frac{u-100}{-84}=e^{-0.016t}\\
 & \Rightarrow & e^{0.016t}=\frac{84}{100-u}
\end{eqnarray*}
Together, this implies
\begin{eqnarray*}
dt & = & \frac{1}{84\cdot0.016}\cdot e^{0.016t}\, du [ \approx 0.744 \cdot e^{0.016t} \,du]\\
 & = & \frac{1}{84\cdot0.016}\cdot\frac{84}{100-u}\, du\\
 & = & \frac{1}{0.016}\cdot\frac{1}{100-u}\, du.
\end{eqnarray*}

Your form of $dt$ is not strictly speaking wrong, but as Antonio Vargas hints at in the comments, you want some expression like $f(u) \,du$, not $f(t) \, du$.

Comment: Thank you! This is great. :D